# How to display this in iPad App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4

How do I show this in iPad application.

[image]

It looks like some kind of modal popup.

What is it called and how do I integrate it in my iPad app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a standard view controller that has been presented modally via the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method of the "parent" view controller. To achieve the exact effect as show in the picture, simply set the `modalPresentationStyle` property to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

If you read the Modal View Controllers section of [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW3) all will be revealed. (It also includes detailed sample code if this is what you require.)